# Why can't gdal open files anymore?

Tags: python, gdal

I have used Gdal for python programming for a while but suddenly it stopped working. Even for the most simply code I get an errormessage:

```
import gdal
file='C:\Users\Documents\image.tif'
ds_in = gdal.Open(file)


ERROR 4:`C:\Users\Documents\image.tif' does not exist in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
```

Comment: Try `'C:\\Users\\Documents\\image.tif'` instead of `'C:\Users\Documents\image.tif'`

Comment: dosn't work either..

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm having the same problem